# dockerize spring boot application with postgresql database for development along with intelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am developing a spring boot applicaition.

I use intelliJ Ultimate.

Generall we use docker compose for setting up like:

```
# My version of docker = 18.09.4-ce
# Compose file format supported till version 18.06.0+ is 3.7
version: "3.7"
services:

  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:11-alpine"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../DO_NOT_DELETE_postgres_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      PGDATA: '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata'
    networks:  # connect to the bridge
      - postgresql_network


  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../DO_NOT_DELETE_pgadmin_data
        target: /var/lib/pgadmin
    networks:
      - postgresql_network


... Here How to make intellij use the openjdk container. I want to use for development


networks:
  postgresql_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I want intelliJ's run command also coupled into the docker system.

How to achieve this.

I want to run the application for development purpose. Later in production i will make the jar and run as `java application.jar` file. I will create seperate docker compose for that

I generally find examples like:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

COPY ./target/demo-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN sh -c 'touch demo-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I know we can run sprint boot application using

```
./mvnm:spring-boot:run
```

So i prefer to just mount the folder and use some `java+maven` docker and then run `./mvnm:spring-boot:run`

Comment: for development purposes why you just not start the container which will start your application? If you want to debug it just expose the jvm debug port in your container and then configure in Intellij a debug to a remote process.

Comment: docker-compose example: ` ports:
      - '8081:8080'
      - '8001:8000'
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:8000'
`  and on Intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/attaching-to-local-process.html